# Display contact name ( Repeats name depends on number of contact number exists to a name)

Tags: android

I want to show "Contact name" and "contact number" in a list. But my code repeats "contact name" depends on how many number or other attributes (i.e. email id ) associated with that particular Name. For example .
In Contact directory contact list as..
Pankaj Kumar and numbers 000000-000 and 00000-2222. I want output as only Pankaj Kumar and primary_number, but output comes with ( Pankaj kumar and number 000000-000) and its repeat with ( Pankaj kumar and number 00000-2222).

How can I solve it.. 
My code is as below ..

  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
    // We'll define a custom screen layout here (the one shown above), but
    // typically, you could just use the standard ListActivity layout.
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_item);

    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,                       // projection
                    null,                       // selection
                    null,                       // selectionArgs
                    Data.DISPLAY_NAME);         // sortOrder        

    startManagingCursor(mCursor); 



    // Now create a new list adapter bound to the cursor.
    // SimpleListAdapter is designed for binding to a Cursor.
    contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, // Context.
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,  // Specify the row template to use (here, two columns bound to the two retrieved cursor rows).
            mCursor,    // Pass in the cursor to bind to.
            new String[] {Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},           // Array of cursor columns to bind to.
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});  // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those columns.

    // Bind to our new adapter.
    setListAdapter(contactAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your query as  follow

```
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
    query( Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null,null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE}, 
                    " DISPLAY_NAME = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))+"'", null, null);
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                switch(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE))){
                case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :break;
                case Phone.TYPE_HOME :break;
                case Phone.TYPE_WORK : String workNo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));break;
                case Phone.TYPE_OTHER :break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

your contact name will not repeat for same number and select whichever number you want to
put as primary form mobile, work, other or home.

Comment: Hi HellBoy, I am going to use your code, And I have a little confusion that if I want to use number which is of TYPE_WORK. Then how can I read that number?